# Simple syntax for iterate 2 list with index

Tags: python, list

Required to run through two lists.

Is there a way to make it easier?

```
for idx, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
```

Comment: What's not easy about this?

Comment: You mean like *magic*?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's not easy. I'm ask, is it way to do this more easy. :)

Comment: Voting to close. Without a definition of "easier", there's no real question being asked. The given code is already pretty minimal.

Answer (score 3):

The other alternative, although I prefer the solution in the question, is:

```
from itertools import count

for i, x, y in zip(count(), seq1, seq2): 
    pass
```

Comment: This is clever actually -- I wouldn't have thought of it.

Comment: Are you sure this is better? I would think that the extra function call to count() inside the zip logic would be heavier than enumerates logic after the zip.

regardless, what about [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)?

Comment: @InbarRose In my answer I did say I don't prefer this, although some people might. As for speed im not sure, this seems like it would be faster but that's just a guess. `izip` would of course be more efficient on Python 2

Comment: I think that the elephant in the room is **WHY** does OP need the index in the first place?  If OP is modifying the lists at higher indices while iterating, maybe he/she doesn't want to use `izip`... (Of course, this should probably then be re-factored as it will break on python3 anyway)...

Answer (score 0):

For different length lists I would use [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead, and it would look like this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for index, (item1, item2) in enumerate(izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=None)): 
    # code
```